# Keep subscripts and superscripts when saving matplotlib chart as .tiff

Tags: python, matplotlib, tiff

I found how to create sub and superscripts in my chart labels using the `$` notation like so:

```
ax.set_ylabel('$kgCO_2e/m^2$')
```

This works fine for creating the chart, but when I save it as a .tiff and try to insert it into a Word document it loses the formatting. Is there a way of doing this that will preserve the formatting?

[issue #1877](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1877)

Comment: Does the `tiff` file (before inserting into word) have the incorrect formatting?  What if you save as a `png` or something else?

Comment: Also, it might help to use a raw string: `ylabel(r'$x^2$')`.  Edit: Nevermind, I think this is mainly for using backslashed latex commands like `\pi`.

Comment: It comes out as expected as a `png`. The `tiff` is saved with incorrect formatting. And using a raw string makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. If you open it up in Photo Viewer the formatting is incorrect so yes, before inserting into Word.

Comment: What is your backend? `print matplotlib.get_backend()`

Comment: That gives me `WXAgg`.

Comment: Can you open an issue for this on the github tracker?  This smells like a bug.

Comment: and can you also post a complete minimal chunk of code to generate the bad tiffs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in `matplotlib`  [issue #1877](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1877).